# OOZIE Hive Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

We are getting errors in oozie hive execution. I copied postgresql jar in oozie libpath and oozie shared libpath also. Please suggest.

> Error: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code
>   [40000]

workflow.xml file

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="hive-wf">
    <start to="hive-node"/>  
    <action name="hive-node">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
        <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/oozie-hive/output-data"/>
                <mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/oozie-hive/output-data"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
        <property>
                    <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                    <value>hive-site.xml</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <script>script.sql</script>
         </hive>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Hive failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

job.properties file

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020
jobTracker=localhost.localdomain:8021
queueName=default
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/oozie-hive/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/oozie-hive
```

hive-site.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera CM on 2016-01-16T07:14:46.882Z-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost.localdomain:7432/hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>cloudera</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.metadata.validate</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.warehouse.subdir.inherit.perms</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
    <value>-1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
    <value>1073741824</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.reducers.max</name>
    <value>999</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.execute.setugi</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost.localdomain</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.client.port</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.namespace</name>
    <value>hive_zookeeper_namespace_hive1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.server.min.threads</name>
    <value>200</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.server.max.threads</name>
    <value>100000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoStartMechanism</name>
    <value>SchemaTable</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

script.sql file

```
CREATE TABLE emp_new (eid INT,ename STRING,esal INT) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/input' overwrite into table emp_new;
```

STDERR

```css
  Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/792403090532364725_1655439530_2002454238/localhost.localdomain/user/cloudera/oozie-hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.7.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/mapred/hive_job_log_2ea9c372-af06-499c-a84e-c0ef36af64f6_993004880.txt
FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
Log file: /mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201601192230_0050/attempt_201601192230_0050_m_000000_0/work/hive-oozie-job_201601192230_0050.log  not present. Therefore no Hadoop jobids found
Intercepting System.exit(1)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [1]
```

script1.sql

```css
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/input' overwrite into table emp;
```

STDERR

```css
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/792403090532364725_1655439530_2002454238/localhost.localdomain/user/cloudera/oozie-hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.7.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/mapred/hive_job_log_bc6f0114-bc56-4a00-8baf-59cf3971b2ae_1694534412.txt
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:67 Exception while processing 'emp': Unable to fetch table emp
Log file: /mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201601192230_0049/attempt_201601192230_0049_m_000000_0/work/hive-oozie-job_201601192230_0049.log  not present. Therefore no Hadoop jobids found
Intercepting System.exit(40000)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [40000]
```

Comment: Could you please share the log present in STDOUT and STDERR in yarn ?

Comment: Hi Karthik,

I shared STDERR log. we are using mapreduce1. 

Thank you..

Comment: @Giri - Your SQL script creates a table called `emp_new` and the STDERR indicates that some piece of your code is trying to access a table called `emp`..  Maybe something to check..

Comment: @vmachan - shared both scripts which i used and errors i got.

Comment: @Giri - I don't see any `CREATE TABLE` for `emp` table..

Comment: @vmachan - emp table already created in hive. I am just trying to load data into it.